# left join in an associative array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make an image gallery. There are albums with images in it and on the index page I want to show witch albums there are and when you click on it you go to that album. I can show the album name but I want to show these albums with the images that is inside that album, with a random function. I hope that you understand what I want to do. 
The problem is that I can't reach the images.

I have two associative arrays, one for the albums and one for the images. the one for the albums looks like this;

```
function get_albums() {
$albums = array();

$albums_query = mysql_query("
SELECT `albums`.`album_id`, `albums`.`timestamp`, `albums`.`name`,     
LEFT(`albums`.`description`, 50) as `description`, COUNT(`images`.`image_id`) as `image_count`
FROM `albums`
LEFT JOIN `images`
ON `albums`.`album_id` = `images`.`album_id`
GROUP BY `albums`.`album_id`
")or die(mysql_error());

while ($albums_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($albums_query)) {
    $albums[] = array(
        'id' => $albums_row['album_id'],
        'timestamp' => $albums_row['timestamp'],
        'name' => $albums_row['name'],
        'description' => $albums_row['description'],
        'count' => $albums_row['image_count']       
        );
}

return $albums;
}
```

And for the images it looks like this;

```
function get_images($album_id) {
$album_id = (int)$album_id;

$images = array();

$image_query = mysql_query("SELECT `image_id`, `image_name`, `album_id`, `timestamp`, `ext` FROM `images` WHERE `album_id`=$album_id");
while ($images_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($image_query)) {
    echo $images_row['image_id'];

    $images[] = array(
    'id' => $images_row['image_id'],
    'img_name' => $images_row['image_name'],
    'album' => $images_row['album_id'],
    'timestamp' => $images_row['timestamp'],
    'ext' => $images_row['ext']
    );
}
return $images;
}
```

I thought that in the get_albums function that with the left join function I gould reach the images by adding the image name and extension like this;

```
while ($albums_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($albums_query)) {
    $albums[] = array(
        'id' => $albums_row['album_id'],
        'timestamp' => $albums_row['timestamp'],
        'name' => $albums_row['name'],
        'description' => $albums_row['description'],
        'count' => $albums_row['image_count'],
        'img_name' => $albums_row['image_name'],
        'ext' => $albums_row['ext']         
        );
```

And then use that in the index page like this;

```
$albums = get_albums();

if (isset($albums)) {
foreach ($albums as $album) {
    echo '<a href="view_album.php?album_id=', $album["id"], '"><img src="uploads/thumbs/', $album["id"] ,'/', $album['img_name'],'.', $album["ext"],'" />', $album['name'], '</a>';
}
}
```

But the result is this;
http://www.robcnossen.nl/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$albums_query` has no img_name or no ext field.

Comment: Thanks Patashu, really simple but I didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make one large query joining all data first, then displaying it as you will, something like this:

```
sql="SELECT * FROM albums a INNER JOIN images i ON a.album_id = i.album_id WHERE a.album_id =" . $album_id;

$result = mysql_query(sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  {
     echo '<a href="view_album.php?album_id=' . $row['album_id'] . '><img src="uploads/thumbs/' . $row['album_id'] . '/' . $row['album_id'] . '.' . $row['album_ext'] . '" />' . $row['album_name'] . '</a>';
}
```

Then it should display exactly how you want it to